# How to completely exit Scrapy shell?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I run my shell using inspect_response() function. I'd like to exit Scrapy shell, so I use Ctrl-D (or Ctrl-Z in Windows) to do this. However, I cannot completely do this, because Spider crawls consecutive URLs, so new Scrapy shells are executed. Do you know any shortcuts to do this without closing the terminal?

```
 def parse_volumes(self, response):
    all_issues = response.css('h6 a')
    for issue in all_issues:
        issue_url = issue.css('::attr(href)').get()
        yield scrapy.Request(issue_url, callback = self.parse_issue)

def parse_issue(self, response):
    for article in response.css('tr'):
        access = article.css('.accessIconContainer div').xpath('./img/@alt').get()
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

Comment: Try `ctrl+c` twice to terminate and `ctrl+z+Enter` to exit.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (which translates to `^Z`) in a prompt and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> didn't work for me, once I'm in scrapy shell, I can't get out to try scraping other URLs.

I need to close the command prompt and activate the environment and start from scratch.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30282765)

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `exit`. That should take you back to your original shell.